# boost::my_map_list_of

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I have some problems with understanding `boost::my_map_list_of` function. Especially this part:

```
operator Map const&() const { return data; }
```

Can any one explain me how it works? And does map created in this way is initialized at compile time?

Below is the whole boost:my_map_list_of() code:

```
template<class K, class V>
struct map_list_of_type {
   typedef std::map<K, V> Map;
  Map data;
  map_list_of_type(K k, V v) { data[k] = v; }
  map_list_of_type& operator()(K k, V v) { data[k] = v; return *this; }
  operator Map const&() const { return data; }
};
template<class K, class V>
map_list_of_type<K, V> my_map_list_of(K k, V v) {
  return map_list_of_type<K, V>(k, v);
}

int main() {
  std::map<int, char> example = 
  my_map_list_of(1, 'a') (2, 'b') (3, 'c');
  cout << example << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, this is now obsolete. C++11 lets you write `std::map<int, char> example { {1,'a'}, {2,'b'} };` etc.

Comment: Kerrek SB: as initializer lists arent supported in for example MSVC, I wouldn't call it obsolete..

Comment: @ViktorSehr: "obsolescent", perhaps...

Answer (score 1):

The code in `main()` is calling the function `my_map_list_of()`, which returns a `map_list_of_type` object:

```
my_map_list_of(1, 'a')
```

Then, `map_list_of_type::operator()` is called on the returned object.  That function returns the same object.

```
my_map_list_of(1, 'a') (2, 'b');
                       ^^^^^^^^
```

And `map_list_of_type::operator()` is called again on the newly returned object.

```
my_map_list_of(1, 'a') (2, 'b') (3, 'c');
                                ^^^^^^^^
```

Then, `map_list_of_type::operator Map const&()` is implicitly called because this assignment demands it.  The object `map_list_of_type<int,char>` is converted to a `std::map<int,char>`

```
std::map<int, char> example = my_map_list_of(1, 'a') (2, 'b') (3, 'c');
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Ok thx, but why in this example we need an conversion to the type Map? I do not get how all that code works. For example how exactly comliper is pasring that line:
"my_map_list_of(1, 'a') (2, 'b') (3, 'c');"
.